# JAVA- Moving an image with arrow keys

Tags: java, swing, awt, arrow-keys

I am making a game for my end-of-year school project, and in my game, a need to be able to move the player around the screen with the arrow keys.
I would like to move the image (playerUpImageLabel) with my arrow keys, but I do not know how. I have tries looking around online on how to do this, but no luck.

The program works as of now, but I do not know how to move the image (playerUpImageLabel) with my arrow keys.

Any Help Please?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Game {

  public void game() {

     JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame();
     JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel();
     JLabel floorLabel = new JLabel();
     JLabel copyrightLabel = new JLabel();

     ImageIcon floorImage = new ImageIcon();

     int playerMovementX;
     int playerMovementY;

     playerMovementX = 280;
     playerMovementY = 280;

     ImageIcon playerUpImage = new ImageIcon();
     JLabel playerUpImageLabel = new JLabel();

     ImageIcon playerLeftImage = new ImageIcon();
     JLabel playerLeftImageLabel = new JLabel();

     ImageIcon playerRightImage = new ImageIcon();
     JLabel playerRightImageLabel = new JLabel();

     ImageIcon playerDownImage = new ImageIcon();
     JLabel playerDownImageLabel = new JLabel();


     ImageIcon playerNormalImage = new ImageIcon();
     JLabel playerNormalImageLabel = new JLabel();

     gameFrame = new JFrame("Zombehs");
     gameFrame.setVisible(true);
     gameFrame.setSize(600, 620);
     gameFrame.setResizable(false);
     gameFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     gameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


     gamePanel = new JPanel();
     gamePanel.setLayout(null);
     gameFrame.add(gamePanel);


     floorImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Users/JakeBorg/Desktop/JavaPro/res/floor.png"));
     floorLabel = new JLabel(floorImage);
     floorLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);


     copyrightLabel = new JLabel("Copyright @ 2016 Jake_Borg");
     copyrightLabel.setFont(new Font("DorFont01", Font.BOLD, 10));
     copyrightLabel.setBounds(500, 580, 100, 10);


     // Player
     playerUpImage = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Users/JakeBorg/Desktop/JavaPro/res/player/Up_1.png"));
     playerUpImageLabel = new JLabel(playerUpImage);
     playerUpImageLabel.setBounds(playerMovementX, playerMovementY, 33,  33);

     playerNormalImageLabel = playerUpImageLabel;



     gamePanel.add(playerNormalImageLabel);
     gamePanel.add(floorLabel);
     gamePanel.add(copyrightLabel);

  }

}
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36894487/java-gui-how-to-move-a-ball-using-wasd-keys/36894544#36894544

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `Key Bindings`. Basically you need to create an `Action` that gets invoked whenever a specific `KeyStroke` is invoked.

Check out [Motion Using The Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for working examples. In addition you will find links to the Swing tutorial explaining `Key Bindings` and `Actions`.